# Sum of Diameter of Unions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a covering of an interval $ [t_1, t_2] $ and a countable union of intervals $ \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} I_k $ that cover the interval $ [t_1, t_2] $.

Can we then conclude that the $ diam([t_1, t_2]) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} diam(I_k) $.

I know the result $ diam(\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} I_k) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} diam(I_k) $ is not true in general. However, I was wondering if it actually is under the given assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can for convex spaces. For an interval, you have the Lebesgue  measure $\lambda(I) = \operatorname{diam} I$, so you directly get
$$\operatorname{diam} I = \lambda ([t_1,t_2]) = \lambda\left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n \right) \leqslant \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda(I) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \operatorname{diam} I_n.$$

This is a property of measures ($\sigma$-summability I believe).

You can generalize this to any convex space $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is covered by an union of convex spaces $C_n$:
Take $x,y \in C$, $[x,y] \in C$, so we just consider $I = [x,y]$ and $I_n = C_n \cap [x,y]$ (still convex). Now we get back to the dimension one case (beware we need homogeneity of the norm for that, a common metric won't do the job), and since $\bigcup_n (C_n \cap [x,y]) = (\bigcup_n C_n) \cap [x,y] = C \cap [x,y] = [x,y]$, we have
$$\|x-y\| \leqslant \sum_n \operatorname{diam} (C_n \cap [x,y]) \leqslant \sum_n \operatorname{diam} C_n$$
Which means
$$ \operatorname{diam} C = \sup_{x,y \in C} \|x-y\| \leqslant \sum_n \operatorname{diam} C_n.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a nice way to use the lebesgue measure to prove it. Also very slick way for higher dimension

Comment: @user007 You can also generalize it with geodesics and $C^1$ path connected covering of a $C^1$ path connected metric space